# Documentum 6.7: class not found exception

Tags: java, documentum

I cannot load my page in browser.
Log in application server show this:

```
12.01.23 09:56:03.149 ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [com.documentum.web.common.Trace] - Errorhandler threw the following error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/documentum/web/security/exceptions/SecurityWrapperRuntimeException
        at jsp_servlet._wdk.__errorhandler._jspService(__errorhandler.java:190)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:158)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:402)
        at jsp_servlet._wdk.__redirect._jspService(__redirect.java:168)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.documentum.web.servlet.ResponseHeaderControlFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.documentum.web.servlet.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:84)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.documentum.web.env.WDKController.processRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.documentum.web.env.WDKController.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
```

I didn't find this class SecurityWrapperRuntimeException in the folder /WEB-INF/lib. What kind jar is it and where I can find it?

Start application in browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use https://www.serfish.com/jar/ or similar sites for this kind of problems